# Not sure if merge array, but something like that

Tags: php

I'm doing a foreach loop to display the 'captions' of the images in my media library. But right now it's showing an array for each item in the wp_query, and I need all of them exploded into a single array so that I can then count like items, etc. What I'm trying to achieve is a weighted word cloud from the words in the captions (I'm using this particular instance of WP as an image library, so I'm querying 'attachment' directly).  Here's my code right now:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'post_mime_type' => 'image',
   'orderby' => 'title',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post();
   $item = get_the_id();
   $image_all = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($item);
   $image_captions = $image_all['caption'];
   $array1 = preg_split('/;|,|; ", /', $image_captions);

   if(!empty($image_captions)) { ?>
      <pre>
         <?php print_r($array1); ?>
      </pre>
   }
endwhile;
```

This results in the following (ad nauseum - a new array for each attachment):

```
Array (
   [0] => woman
   [1] =>  fashion
   [2] =>  winter
   [3] =>  fur
   [4] =>  chignon
)

Array (
   [0] => woman
   [1] =>  fashion
   [2] =>  winter
   [3] =>  snow
   [4] =>  hat
   [5] =>  fur
)

Array (
   [0] => woman
   [1] =>  fashion
   [2] =>  generic
   [3] =>  hat
   [4] =>  purse
)

Array (
   [0] => pop-up shop
   [1] =>  vertical
   [2] =>  standee
)
```

I need to get all the arrays joined together into 1 array(I'm assuming), so that I can then count the number of occurrences of each term, and eliminate duplicates, display a count of the number of times a term occurs, and then display them as a weighted cloud of some sort. I'm just trying to figure out this first step right now (though if anyone is inclined to help me get through the rest of it, I'd be very grateful).

Comment: Why are you assuming? What is going to use the array(s)? What is it expecting?

Comment: May be a loop & and array_merge!! Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Daniel - I'm assuming because I'm not an expert. I have explained what I will be trying to do with the array. And I *thought* I was fairly clear on what I'm expecting for an output in order to proceed with the end goal. If my assumption is incorrect, I'm looking for direction on how best to proceed.

Comment: @sougata - I have tried an array_merge. It didn't change the output. But I've never done one before, so it's possible I didn't do it right.